# Hadoop : How to compute actual file size?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am using hadoop to store files. I want to know the actual file size.

```
getFileSystem().getContentSummary(new Path(fileName)).getLength();
```

It returns the compressed file size. I am using default hadoop codec compression.

How can I compute the actual file size?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the compression codec supports storing the uncompressed size in a header / footer of the compressed file there is no way to work out the uncompressed size (other than performing a stream decompress and running via something like dd or count the bytes in java).

GZip for example - the last 4 bytes of the file are the uncompressed size in bytes (assuming it's not more than 4 bytes can represent)